# Integrating HTML2PDF in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, html2pdf

I'm trying to integrate [HTML2PDF library](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default)  in [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com)

They doesn't support [composer](http://getcomposer.org) so I downloaded the latest version of html2pdf

and put it to Laravel vendor directory and called the library from routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hello WOlrd</p>');
$html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');

});
```

but I'm keep getting this error

```
  Whoops
  ErrorException
  Undefined property: HTML2PDF::$_subFIRST_HEADER
```

Anyone have a solution about how to integrate html2pdf in laravel 4 ?

Comment: try dom2pdf it supports composer install too http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to use a couple of libraries that don't have composer support. What I did was create a folder called 'libraries' in 'app/' directory in the root of you Laravel 4 project. Then I added a line of code to app/start/global.php:

```
<?php

ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

        app_path().'/commands',
        app_path().'/controllers',
        app_path().'/models',
        app_path().'/database/seeds',
        app_path().'/libraries', // ADDED this line

    ));
```

Note: I've not done this before with HTML2PDF, so can't be 100% sure it will work. I think the directory structure of files in the app/libraries folder will have to follow the namespacing used in the library (if they use namespaces that is)